# How to remove a File from the File System in a XPages System Event

Tags: java, xpages

I want to remove a File, when a Session is terminated, however, when trying to modify a File from the File System, I get a Notes Security Exception.

Here is what I have tried:

```
File f = getSourceFile();    
f.delete(); // java.lang.SecurityException: Zugriff auf die Datei {0} bzw. diese zu ändern ist nicht zulässig (Accessing or modifiying this File is prohibited)

FileUtils.clearFile(f); // java.lang.IllegalStateException: NotesContext is not initialized for the Thread
```

This is how I retrieve my File:

```
public File getSourceFile() {
    return new File(this.absolutePath);
}
```

I also tried using doPrivileged but that caused the same IllegalStateException:

```
AccessController.doPrivileged(new PrivilegedAction() { // java.lang.IllegalStateException: NotesContext is not initialized for the Thread
    public Object run() {   
        File f = getSourceFile();
            if(f.exists()){
                FileUtil.deleteFile(f);
            }
    }
});
```

I guess it would be Possible to reinitialize the NotesContext somehow, but I don't think that would be an elegant solution.

The Stacktraces:

(Illegal State)

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: NotesContext not initialized for the thread&#xD;
at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NotesContext.getCurrent(NotesContext.java:123)&#xD;
at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.ModuleClassLoader$DynamicClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:438)&#xD;
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassHelper(ClassLoader.java:924)&#xD;
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:869)&#xD;
at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.ModuleClassLoader$DynamicClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:403)&#xD;
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:852)&#xD;
at de.iV.beans.ticket.file.FileWrapper.clear(FileWrapper.java:90)&#xD;
at de.iV.beans.ticket.Ticket.clearFiles(Ticket.java:155)&#xD;
at de.iV.session.CustomSessionListener.sessionDestroyed(CustomSessionListener.java:46)&#xD;
at com.ibm.xsp.application.ApplicationSessionListener.sessionDestroyed(ApplicationSessionListener.java:53)&#xD;
at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule.notifySessionRemoved(ComponentModule.java:370)&#xD;
at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule.checkSessionTimeout(ComponentModule.java:239)&#xD;
at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFComponentModule.checkTimeout(NSFComponentModule.java:213)&#xD;
at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFService.checkTimeout(NSFService.java:281)&#xD;
at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.LCDEnvironment.checkTimeout(LCDEnvironment.java:247)&#xD;
at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.bootstrap.BootstrapEnvironment.tellCommand(BootstrapEnvironment.java:388)&#xD;
at com.ibm.domino.xsp.bridge.http.engine.XspCmdManager.tell(XspCmdManager.java:92
```

(Security)

```
    java.lang.SecurityException: Zugriff auf die Datei {0} bzw. diese zu ändern ist nicht zulässig
at lotus.notes.AgentSecurityManager.checkDelete(Unknown Source)
at java.io.File.delete(File.java:1047)
at de.iV.beans.ticket.file.FileWrapper.clear(FileWrapper.java:94)
at de.iV.beans.ticket.Ticket.clearFiles(Ticket.java:155)
at de.iV.session.CustomSessionListener.sessionDestroyed(CustomSessionListener.java:46)
at com.ibm.xsp.application.ApplicationSessionListener.sessionDestroyed(ApplicationSessionListener.java:53)
at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule.notifySessionRemoved(ComponentModule.java:370)
at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule.checkSessionTimeout(ComponentModule.java:239)
at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFComponentModule.checkTimeout(NSFComponentModule.java:213)
at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFService.checkTimeout(NSFService.java:281)
at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.LCDEnvironment.checkTimeout(LCDEnvironment.java:247)
at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.bootstrap.BootstrapEnvironment.tellCommand(BootstrapEnvironment.java:388)
at com.ibm.domino.xsp.bridge.http.engine.XspCmdManager.tell(XspCmdManager.java:92)
```

I was not able to figure out a workaround.

Comment: Have you updated java.policy or java.pol file on your domino server https://www.wissel.net/blog/2011/07/java-security-in-xpages.html  ? Does the signer have enough privileges?

Comment: Signer has enough privileges, modifying the pol file works, but I was hoping I could solve it differently somehow. I just don't like the idea that my Application relies on such a Setting (that is not accessible through the Designer/Notes UI), but thanks a lot for a working solution anyway...

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 options:

- Edit java.policy (or create java.pol - not on 11.0)
- Move your code into an osgi plugin

For the later: it isn't as scary as it sounds. Your plugin would live in an updatesite.nsf

Check [this deck](https://www.slideshare.net/fiorep/domino-osgi-development) for getting started info.

Comment: Do you have any other/more Information regarding xPages osgi Libraries? or maybe some boilerplate code? I tried reconstructing the Hello World Library from the Slideshow but unfortunately, after installing the local update site, the Control just doesn't show up in the Control Pallete and the Library ID is not listed in the XSP props. I could not locate any repo for the slideshow. Most tutorials online just explain how to set up your Eclipse environment...

Comment: Head over to OpenNTF.org. In their repos on GitHub are a number of OSGi plugins with complete source

Comment: Here is a small plugin as boiler plate: https://github.com/hasselbach/domino-quartz

Answer (score 1):

I did a quick test, and everything worked without a problem. ND9 & ND10.

A Session listener, a file deletion in "Session Destroyed"-Event, no java.policy modification.

**EDIT:**
Ah, got it. It has nothing to do with the file deletion. It is a ClassLoader problem when accessing classes in your NSF from the "Session Destroyed"-Event.